# node js and postgresql returning undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, express, psql

I am trying to select data from my database table and then print it in the console. whenever I try the console returns undefined.

```
const sql = await pool.query("SELECT * FROM users");
    for(rows in sql){
        console.log(rows.username)
    }
```

Comment: Have you read the documentation? `for(rows in sql){` is not how to access the results of the query

Comment: Try logging `sql` to see what you're doing wrong

Answer (score 2):

To get an array out of pool.query, you need to do the following:

```
const result = await pool.query("SELECT * FROM users");

const users = result.rows // get an array of users
```

If you want to get all the username from the users table, you can do:

```
const usernames = users.map((user) => user.username); // get an array of usernames
```